# SQL CE SELECT Convert

Tags: sql

I'm trying to convert a DateTime field (Date of Birth), within the an SELECT FROM that needs to work for SQL CE and SQL Access databases.

I've found a thread that shows me that it can be done, but not the formate I want it to be.  Does anyone know how I can change this to show yyyy-mm-dd format not mm/dd/yyyy

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10),  C.DOB,101)  FROM table
```

Comment: There's a difference between value and format. Each RDBMS can store a date value differently, but if everithing is ok, it **will** be a date. As for the format, you can use format functions to show it anyway you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), C.DOB, 120) AS FormatedDate FROM Table
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure why 120 and 21 seem to do the same result

Comment: you can see the complete list here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to find how I can do it.  Its using the convert function, but the code passed into it is different

So to get the correct format, I need the below code

```
 CONVERT(nvarchar(10),  A.TestDate,21)
```

[enter link description here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237895%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)